# Massive growth in Binlog file size

Tags: mysql

Question:

Why Binlog size grows drastically when isolation level set to "Repeatable Read" & When isolation level set to "Read Committed"
the size of Binlog file reduces ?

Environment: RDS Mysql 8.0.28 Multi-AZ Enabled

Summary:

Recently, we have migrated our Mysql RDS instance from 5.7 to 8.0.28 & it is observed that the size of
Binlog file grows drastically from 500gb to 1TB+. The retention period of Binlog file is set to 24 hours & Binlog format is Mixed.

To mitigate this issue, we have changed the binlog file retention to 6 hours & changed the isolation level
from "Repeatable Read" to "Read Committed" & we see the size of binlog file has reduced to approx. 10gb.

Comment: You should read the docs about that, the rest depends on the application you are using. (Like: - Average time use per transaction; - Number (simultaneous) of transactions; - number of concurrent users; - ....... )

Comment: This question really belongs on dba.stackexchange.com, because it isn't a question about code. It's a question about database operation. So I cast a vote to move the question to that site.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log-setting.html says:

> If you are using InnoDB tables and the transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED, only row-based logging can be used.

Since you have set the binlog format to MIXED, I believe using READ-COMMITTED implicitly logs all events in ROW based format.

It's not unusual for ROW-based binlog format to cause the log file to be a lot larger, because each binlog event contains a copy of the whole row, not just the SQL statement. In fact, ROW-based binlog events contain the whole row *before and after* the change, so there are two copies!

For example, in an application I supported, the application made frequent updates like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET status = 2 WHERE id = 12345;
```

This seems like a simple change, but the table also had some large BLOB/TEXT columns, which were copied into the binlog row image, even though they were not changed by the UPDATE.

The impact of this is that when we switched that application to ROW-based binary logging (this is normally a good thing because it helps to reduce risk of replication infidelity), the binlogs became *HUGE*. They grew so large, in fact, that they could not be transferred over the network to replicas as rapidly as they were growing on the source instance, and the replica kept falling behind.

The solution we used was to set this config option in the MySQL Server's my.cnf: [binlog_row_image=MINIMAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_row_image). This makes the "before" row image include only the primary key, and the "after" image includes only the columns that changed.